# How to avoid creating models in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am developing an app which has lot of network calls and i am using retrofit for it.For each request i have created model class and this resulted in large number of model classes.So is there any way to avoid creating unnecessary model classes.

Comment: You mean Gson model classes? Yes, there is a way. Don't use Gson, and just parse the JSON strings yourself

Comment: Can you please add some sample code ?

Comment: or always parse to a hashmap or array of hashmap

Comment: @cricket_007: yes ,how can i disable default pojo mapping and use simple json strings like in volley.

Comment: @Androidjack Yes its not mandatory to have model class for each request. If its not required then you can simply have retrofit Response and then u can get json from response object and parse it if its required.

Comment: It sounds like you just want OkHttp instead of Retrofit, but *by default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's ResponseBody type* -- In other words, the Gson converter is completely optional.

Answer (score 1):

For receiving you can use `JsonElement` as response. For request you can create json in string and send it as I desctibe below:

**Interface**

```
@POST("api/")
    Call<JsonElement> request(@Body RequestBody body);
```

**Request:**

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), inputJsonString);
     call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                        if(jsonElement.isJsonObject()){
                        //use any json deserializer to convert to your class.
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(response.message());
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can avoid the unnecessary model classes.

for example:
suppose you have 5 model classes, `Model_class1` is main model class and you have to declare other 4 sub model classes.

```
class Model_class1
{
  @SerializedName("Model_class2")
  @Expose
   private Model_class2 model_class2;

 @SerializedName("Model_class3")
  @Expose
  private Model_class3 model_class3;

 @SerializedName("Model_class4")
  @Expose
private Model_class4 model_class4;

 @SerializedName("Model_class5")
  @Expose
 private Model_class5 model_class5;

}
```

In above code snippet if you want only `Model_class2` and `Model_class3` means you have to declare only those model names in `Model_class1` and remaining two. No need to declare and no need create those two model classes also.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can atleast of sending request but for receiving i have never tried.

Use JSONObject or JSONArray and pass them to retrofit as **@Body**

```
try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("username", "username");
        obj.put("password", "password");
        RetrofitInterface.login(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is your retrofit interface class

```
public interface RetrofitInterface{
  .
  .
  @POST(URL)
  Call login(@Body JSONObject object);
  .
  .
}
```